# Can Jackson deserialize into Map<Long, String> with just annotations?

Tags: java, json, dictionary, jackson, json-deserialization

I have a json string containing a map property such as

```
{"map":{"1":"value"}, ...}
```

When Jackson deserializes this into the class containing the an attribute `Map<Long, String> map`, it seems to do a `map.put(null,"1=value")`. While on the serialization it will serialize the object into the same format.

Is there a way to have jackson correctly deserialize into a Map with only annotations or will I need to make a custom serializer.

Example Object with getter/setter:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.MINIMAL_CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@class")
public class exampleObject {
  Map<Long, String> valueMap;

  public Map<Long, String> getValueMap() {
    return valueMap;
  }

  public void setValueMap(Map<Long, String> valueMap) {
    this.valueMap = valueMap;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class ExampleObject {

    private Map<String, Long> valueMap;

    @JsonCreator
    public AccountTagVariableDescription(Map<String, Long> valueMap) {
        this.valueMap = valueMap;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Long> getValueMap() {
        return valueMap;
    }
}
```